# Majorana fields and attributed supercharges

Tags: spinors

Numbr of components for a Majorana field in D-dim is equal to $2^([D/2]-1)$. Now, what is the number of attributed supercharges to the Majorana field?

Comment: Your question does not make sense. Spinors are certain irreducible representations of $\mathfrak{so}(1,d-1)$ or $\mathfrak{so}(d)$, and not "eigenvectors", in particular they have got nothing to do with SU(2) in arbitrary dimensions. The classification of spin representations is moreover rather easy to find in many texts, so this question does not show any research effort,.

Comment: Sorry if my question didn't make sense to you. I'd read these sentences  some where and copied here because it was a bit vague for me as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $SU(2)$ the spinor representation has dimension 2. Your questions is not clear, but for rotation groups (or more precisely, their associated spin groups), we have:

For $so(2n)$ (with $n\ge 2$), there are two spinor representations of dimension is $2^{n-1}$. E.g., for $so(2\times 5)$, the spinor is 16.

For odd dimensions, $so(2n+1)$, the spinors have dimension $2^n$.

Comment: Exactly, thank you. But I'm mainly confused about the number of supercharges.